# Validate one two asterisks at the beginning of a word

Tags: regex

Need to validate if a word has one or maximum two asterisks at the beginning of a word, from three onwards it should ignore them.

**words**:

```
[
 '* 11 13 24.574 1,474.79'
 '** 11 13 24.574 1,474.79'
 '*** 11 13 24.574 1,474.79'
]
```

**Test**:

```
1. ^[**]
2. ^[*][*]
3. (^\*{1}\s)
4. ^\*|\*\s
```

**Expected**:

```
[
 '* 11 13 24.574 1,474.79',
 '** 11 13 24.574 1,474.79'
]
```

Comment: Instead of 'word', do you mean 'line'? And are you looking for a regex that will only match lines that start with one or two asterisks, followed by a space? Are the expressions under 'Test:' the ones you tried so far? Why not just `^\*\*?\s`?

Comment: @Grismar test: they are the regex that I have tried and nothing regexr.com/5b0r9, `^\*\*?\s` is not the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say words I'll assume you have all of the "words" listed in a vector. That should look like:

```
 string_vector <- c("* 11 13 24.574 1,474.79", "** 11 13 24.574 1,474.79", "*** 11 13 24.574 1,474.79")
```

The problem with test 1 is that [] selects either of the elements inside the brackets, so ^[**] just searches for one asterisk at the start of the string. All 3 words will be matched. Test two will match any case where there are 2 asterisks at the beginning which includes all 3 of the strings in your vector. Test 3 matches exactly one asterisk at the beginning followed by a space which will only return the first item. Test 4 matches either one asterisk at the beginning or an asterisk followed by a space anywhere in the string which will result in matches in all items in the vector. You would need to use the `^` after the `|` to have the choice be between two different patterns as the first character. However, it's not clear why this would apply to your question as 2 asterisks at the beginning wouldn't be matched. You can test all of this for yourself by using the "str_view_all" function in the stringr pacakge. You will need to use two backslashes before the `*` and `s` if they're not in square brackets.

I suggest using the following:

```
    library(stringr)
    str_subset(string_vector,"^\\*{1,2}[^*].+")
```

This matches all elements of your vector which have exactly 1 or 2 asterisks at the beginning `"^\\*{1,2}"` and not any more asterisks connected to the original one or two `[^*]`. Then the `".+"` means any other characters can occupy the rest of the string.

This command gives your desired output

```
    [1] "* 11 13 24.574 1,474.79"  "** 11 13 24.574 1,474.79"
```

you can assign to an object if you want to do more with the resulting vector

```
    object <- str_subset(string_vector,"^\\*{1,2}[^*].+")
```

EDIT based on Cary Swoveland's helpful comments:

If just `"**"` and `"*"`  are also supposed to be matched, then the following expression should work. Based on the provided data I assumed there would always be more characters following the `*`'s at the beginning, but I now see that there was no explicit statement in the description which would logically lead to this assumption.

```
    object <- str_subset(string_vector,"^*(?!\\*)|^\\*{2}(?!\\*)")
```

This will match:

1. one `*` not followed by another `*` OR
2. two `*` not followed by another `*`

The `(?!)` represents a negative lookahead. i.e. the character(s) to be matched (in this case 1 or 2 `*`) cannot immediately precede the character in parentheses after `(?!)` (in this case another `*` which is escaped with `\\`). Cary is also correct in pointing out that since we're only interested in how the string begins, it doesn't matter if there are any more characters after the 1 or 2 `*` of interest.

Comment: It's not clear if the strings `"*"` and `"**"` are to be matched, but if so your regex will fail.

Answer (score 2):

**This might work for you:**

https://regex101.com/r/OyGxta/2

**Test String:**

```
* 11 13 24.574 1,474.79
** 11 13 24.574 1,474.79
*** 11 13 24.574 1,474.79
```

**Pattern:**

```
^\*{1,2}(?!\*).*
```

Comment: You're right to end with .* as opposed to .+ like I did

Comment: Does `.*` at the end have any effect? Keep in mind that the regex is only needed for validation.

Comment: That's a valid point -- I just did it because thought they might want the line of text. I suppose it could be further reduced.